# Issue with adding a new disk to a server

Tags: centos, lvm

I've added a LVM disk to a Centos 6 server. After adding the disk, i used the command `echo '- - -' > host0/scan` to scan for the new disk, which has just added to the server.

After that, i could see the new disk by using the command `fdisk -l`. However, i could see the LVM device, which belong to the same disk, only after i've rebooted the server.

This what i got after adding the new disk:

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 751.6 GB, 751619276800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91379 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x119722fe

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       91379   734001786   83  Linux
```

And the following is what has been added after rebooting the server:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/data-lv: 751.6 GB, 751615082496 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91378 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Is there a way to make the LVM device to show up without rebooting the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vgchange -a y` should activate all your LVM devices, or

`vgchange -a y <vg_name>` to active a single one,

both actions without the need for a reboot.

From `man vchange`:

> DESCRIPTION
>          vgchange allows you to change the attributes  of  one  or  more  volume
>          groups. Its main purpose is to activate and deactivate VolumeGroupName,
>          or all volume groups if none is specified.  Only active  volume  groups
>          are subject to changes and allow access to their logical volumes.
>
> -a, --activate [a|e|l]{y|n}
>                 Controls the availability of the logical volumes in  the  volume
>                 group  for input/output.  In other words, makes the logical volumes known/unknown to the kernel.  If autoactivation  option  is
>                 used  (-aay),  each  logical volume in the volume group is acti‐
>                 vated only if it matches an item in the  activation/auto_activation_volume_list  set in lvm.conf. If this list is not set, then
>                 all volumes are considered  for  activation.   The  -aay  option
>                 should  be  also  used  during  system  boot so it's possible to
>                 select which volumes to activate using the activation/auto_acti‐
>                 vation_volume_list settting.